# How to share app data among different android devices

Tags: android, preferences

Users have Android phone and tablet. They want to use the application with same settings and sync data. Any suggestion how to develop this feature?

Thanks

Comment: What is the part you're stuck on? Reading/writing preferences? Communicating between devices? Synchronization methods?